# How to import csv file into JqGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, csv, jqgrid

I have a application where I am displaying data using JQGrid (I am new to JQGrid). Application is for the client which do not understand English. So for that the data which we need to display can be displayed in there naive language via DB, where as I need to show Column Names, Grid Caption, Loading Grid Message.....etc using a csv file. I have searched and find there is no direct support for csv in JQGrid. But we can do that using any other workaround?

I'll show my code snippet.

```
    jQuery("#jQGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'Handler1.ashx',
        datatype: 'json',
        toppager: 'false',
        height: 300,
        colNames: [strPersonID, strLastName, strFirstName, strAddress, strCity],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'ID', width: 60, index: 'ID', stype: 'text', search: false, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'LastName', width: 100, index: 'LastName', stype: 'text', sortable: true },
                    { name: 'FirstName', width: 100, index: 'FirstName', align: 'center', stype: 'text', classes: 'hyperlink', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'http://localhost:58404/About.aspx' } },
                    { name: 'Address', width: 100, index: 'Address', stype: 'text', search: false, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'City', width: 100, index: 'City', stype:'select', editoptions:{value:":;Bangalore:Bangalore;Chennai:Chennai;Pune:Pune;Bombay:Bombay;Lucknow:Lucknow;Delhi:Delhi;Agra:Agra"}, sortable: true }
                    ],
        rowNum: 10,
        mtype: 'GET',
        loadonce: true,
        loadtext: strLoading,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30], 
        viewrecords: true,
        sortname: 'ID',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        caption: strListEmployeeDetails,
        shrinkToFit: 'false'
    });
```

These column names, loadtext and Caption I have to pull from csv file.

The code behind for the same :

```
UIContentController uiContentController = new UIContentController();

        string strPersonID = uiContentController.GetText("Start_JqGrid_strPersonID", null);
        string strLastName = uiContentController.GetText("Start_JqGrid_strLastName", null);
        string strFirstName = uiContentController.GetText("Start_JqGrid_strFirstName", null);
        string strAddress = uiContentController.GetText("Start_JqGrid_strAddress", null);
        string strCity = uiContentController.GetText("Start_JqGrid_strCity", null);
        string strListEmployeeDetails = uiContentController.GetText("Start_JqGrid_strListEmployeeDetails", null);
        string strLoading = uiContentController.GetText("Start_JqGrid_strLoading", null);

        jqGridColConstant = jqGridColConstant + "var strPersonID = '" + strPersonID + "';";
        jqGridColConstant = jqGridColConstant + "var strLastName = '" + strLastName + "';";
        jqGridColConstant = jqGridColConstant + "var strFirstName = '" + strFirstName + "';";
        jqGridColConstant = jqGridColConstant + "var strAddress = '" + strAddress + "';";
        jqGridColConstant = jqGridColConstant + "var strCity = '" + strCity + "';";
        jqGridColConstant = jqGridColConstant + "var strListEmployeeDetails = '" + strListEmployeeDetails + "';";
        jqGridColConstant = jqGridColConstant + "var strLoading = '" + strLoading + "';";
        jqGridColConstant = jqGridColConstant + "</script>";

if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jqGridColConstant"))
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "jqGridColConstant", jqGridColConstant);
```

My csv file entries are:

```
246,Start_JqGrid_strPersonID,Person_ID
247,Start_JqGrid_strLastName,Last Name
248,Start_JqGrid_strFirstName,First Name
249,Start_JqGrid_strAddress,Address
250,Start_JqGrid_strCity,City
251,Start_JqGrid_strListEmployeeDetails,Employee Details
252,Start_JqGrid_strLoading,Loading...
```

currently this is in English, but going further client will change the csv file according to his need

This approach is not giving the desired result.
any solution or workaround?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am very surprised to know that no one has even tried to answer my question.....

Most of the googling says there is no direct support to import data/JQGrid property values from csv.

So finally after some research I got the answer on my own question. its like this:

Only change in the above code sample would be in .ascx file only at the time of declaring column name, LoadText & caption....

```
colNames: [''+strPersonID+'', ''+strLastName+'', ''+strFirstName+'', ''+strAddress+'', ''+strCity+''],
loadtext: ''+strJQGridLoadingMessage+'',
caption: ''+strCurrentRequestHeaderCaption+'',
```

Please note that its not **double cores** I used there its two **single cores** only....
Using this I am able to achieve what I wanted too.

Thanks All,
Aashu...